# Solr Lucene , Index Limit

Tags: solr, indexing, lucene

I have tried to index a very huge xml document. (**~1.5 gb, 6.5M row**)

When i command

```
java -jar post.jar file_name.xml
```

process takes a half minute and says "1 file indexed". But queries don't performe and the number of document in solr admin panel doesn't change.

Is there any limit for indexing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a transmission-dictated limit of 2GB, so theoretically your call should work. However, posting an XML document of 1.5GB is likely to take quite a lot more memory than 1.5GB to process. 30 seconds for 6.5M rows (which I guess means 6.5M documents) also sounds way too fast. Check your Solr log for OutOfMemory errors.